# How to create relationships in Orient-DB?

Tags: graph, relationships, graph-databases, orientdb

I having a stuck with relationships in Orient-DB.

My problem is i dont know  how to create relationships in orient-DB?

I was read document and see it have command CREATE LINK. but i dont know how do it can create link when i insert new record and don't run command CREATE LINK.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE LINK is only when you import from RDBMS and it transforms FOREIGN KEYS to links. To create a link just put the target's RID into the source object. What API are you using?

Comment: Hi Lvca!

I do example follow this page https://code.google.com/p/orient/wiki/ImportFromRDBMS

And when i want insert a record to comment table a new record.

My problem is I don't know How to field comments of post table can update ? 

Thanks !

Comment: Sorry I've not understood, can you elaborate better?

Answer (score 0):

I have a example simple example simple

I have two table. Post and comment.

TABLE POST:

```
+----+----------------+
| id | title          |
+----+----------------+
| 10 | NoSQL movement |
| 20 | New OrientDB   |
+----+----------------+
```

TABLE COMMENT:

```
+----+--------+--------------+
| id | postId | text         |
+----+--------+--------------+
|  0 |   10   | First        |
|  1 |   10   | Second       |
| 21 |   10   | Another      |
| 41 |   20   | First again  |
| 82 |   20   | Second Again |
+----+--------+--------------+
```

So now. i run command :

```
 CREATE LINK comments TYPE linkset FROM comment.postId To post.id INVERSE.
```

In table post will change to :

TABLE POST:

```
+----+----------------++----------------+
| id | title          | comments
+----+----------------++----------------+
| 10 | NoSQL movement |[#7:0,#7:1,#7:2]
| 20 | New OrientDB   |[#7:3,#7:4]
+----+----------------++----------------+
```

So now. i want insert a record to comment table.

I run  this command :

```
INSERT INTO COMMENT (id, postId, text) VALUES( 5, 10, 'Six' );
```

My problem is I don't know How to post table can update to :

```
  +----+----------------++----------------+
    | id | title          | comments
    +----+----------------++----------------+
    | 10 | NoSQL movement |[#7:0,#7:1,#7:2,#7:5]
    | 20 | New OrientDB   |[#7:3,#7:4]
    +----+----------------++----------------+
```

Thanks !

Comment: why you are posting your problem as answer

Answer (score 0):

You Should Use this

```
begin
let a=INSERT INTO COMMENT (id, postId, text) VALUES( 5, 10, 'Six' );
let b=update post add children=$s where @rid=YOUR_POST_RID/ID
commit
return $b;
```

/*****update #13:0 add children=#12:1   you can also do like this where #13:0 is post id while #12:1 is comment id **********/

Answer (score 0):

Im using the Java API and woundering what is the best practice to maintain relationship between documents. Right now Im doing it like this:

```
protected static ODocument addReference(ODocument d1, ODocument d2) {
        Collection<ODocument> ref = d1.field(FIELD_ID, OType.LINKSET);
        if(ref == null) {
            ref = new HashSet<>();
        }
        ref = new HashSet<>(ref);
        ref.add(d2);
        return d1.field(FIELD_ID, ref, OType.LINKSET).save();
    }
}
```

But I run into NPE or ClassCastExceptions quite frequently so I doubt this is the right way to do it.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to know this too. So far as I can tell the documentation doesn't ever explain, for the document api, how to actually add relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Right now I am using this class which is working as expected so far.

```java
public class DocumentsReferences {

    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DocumentsReferences.class);

    private static void addToReferenceCollection(ODocument orid, String className, String fieldName, ORID value) {

    Collection<ORID> refCollection = new HashSet<>(getReferenceCollection(orid, className, fieldName));
    refCollection.add(value);
    setReferenceCollection(orid, className, fieldName, refCollection);
    }

    public static void establishMany2ManyRelationship(ODocument documentFirst, String classNameFirst,
        String fieldNameFirst, ODocument documentSecond, String classNameSecond, String fieldNameSecond) {

    // left side
    addToReferenceCollection(documentFirst, classNameFirst, fieldNameFirst, documentSecond.getIdentity());
    // right side
    addToReferenceCollection(documentSecond, classNameSecond, fieldNameSecond, documentFirst.getIdentity());
    }

    public static void establishMany2OneRelationship(ODocument documentFirst, String classNameFirst,
        String fieldNameFirst, ODocument documentSecond, String classNameSecond, String fieldNameSecond) {

    // left side
    setReference(documentFirst, classNameFirst, fieldNameFirst, documentSecond);
    // right side
    addToReferenceCollection(documentSecond, classNameSecond, fieldNameSecond, documentFirst.getIdentity());
    }

    public static void establishOne2ManyRelationship(ODocument documentFirst, String classNameFirst,
        String fieldNameFirst, ODocument documentSecond, String classNameSecond, String fieldNameSecond) {

    // left side
    addToReferenceCollection(documentFirst, classNameFirst, fieldNameFirst, documentSecond.getIdentity());
    // right side
    setReference(documentSecond, classNameSecond, fieldNameSecond, documentFirst);
    }

    public static void establishOne2OneRelationship(ODocument documentFirst, String classNameFirst,
        String fieldNameFirst, ODocument documentSecond, String classNameSecond, String fieldNameSecond) {

    // left side
    setReference(documentFirst, classNameFirst, fieldNameFirst, documentSecond);
    // right side
    setReference(documentSecond, classNameSecond, fieldNameSecond, documentFirst);
    }

    public static ORID getReference(ODocument document, String className, String fieldName) {

    if (isValid(document, className)) {
        OIdentifiable result = document.field(fieldName, OType.LINK);
        if (result == null) {
        return null;
        }
        return result.getIdentity();
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("For " + document);
    }

    public static Collection<ORID> getReferenceCollection(ODocument document, String className, String fieldName) {

    if (isValid(document, className)) {
        try {
        Collection<OIdentifiable> result = document.field(fieldName, OType.LINKSET);
        if (result == null) {
            return Collections.emptySet();
        }
        return result.stream().map(identifiable -> identifiable.getIdentity())
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
        } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
        return Collections.emptySet();
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("For " + document);
    }

    public static boolean isValid(ODocument document, String className) {

    return Documents.isValid(document, className);
    }

    /**
     * @return {@link Collection} of {@link ORID ORIDs} of all documents that
     *         have been deleted during this operation
     */
    public static Collection<ORID> releaseMany2ManyRelationship(ODocument documentFirst, String classNameFirst,
        String fieldNameFirst, Collection<? extends ODocument> documentsSecond, String classNameSecond,
        String fieldNameSecond, boolean autoDeleteEmpty) {

    Collection<ORID> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ODocument documentSecond : documentsSecond) {
        // left side
        boolean documentFirstIsEmpty = removeFromReferenceCollection(documentFirst, classNameFirst, fieldNameFirst,
            documentSecond.getIdentity());
        if (documentFirstIsEmpty && autoDeleteEmpty && !result.contains(documentFirst.getIdentity())) {
        result.add(documentFirst.delete().save().getIdentity());
        }
        // right side
        boolean documentSecondIsEmpty = removeFromReferenceCollection(documentSecond, classNameSecond,
            fieldNameSecond, documentFirst.getIdentity());
        if (documentSecondIsEmpty && autoDeleteEmpty && !result.contains(documentSecond.getIdentity())) {
        result.add(documentSecond.delete().save().getIdentity());
        }
    }
    if (!result.isEmpty()) {
        logger.debug("Auto-deleted empty: " + result);
    }
    return result;
    }

    /**
     * @return {@link Collection} of {@link ORID ORIDs} of all documents that
     *         have been deleted during this operation
     */
    public static Collection<ORID> releaseMany2ManyRelationship(ODocument documentFirst, String classNameFirst,
        String fieldNameFirst, ODocument documentSecond, String classNameSecond, String fieldNameSecond,
        boolean autoDeleteEmpty) {

    return releaseMany2ManyRelationship(documentFirst, classNameFirst, fieldNameFirst,
        Arrays.asList(documentSecond), classNameSecond, fieldNameSecond, autoDeleteEmpty);
    }

    public static void releaseMany2OneRelationship(ODocument documentFirst, String classNameFirst,
        String fieldNameFirst, ODocument documentSecond, String classNameSecond, String fieldNameSecond) {

    // left side
    setReference(documentFirst, classNameFirst, fieldNameFirst, null);
    // right side
    removeFromReferenceCollection(documentSecond, classNameSecond, fieldNameSecond, documentFirst.getIdentity());
    }

    public static void releaseOne2ManyRelationship(ODocument documentFirst, String classNameFirst,
        String fieldNameFirst, Collection<? extends ODocument> documentsSecond, String classNameSecond,
        String fieldNameSecond) {

    for (ODocument documentSecond : documentsSecond) {
        // left side
        removeFromReferenceCollection(documentFirst, classNameFirst, fieldNameFirst, documentSecond.getIdentity());
        // right side
        setReference(documentSecond, classNameSecond, fieldNameSecond, null);
    }
    }

    public static void releaseOne2ManyRelationship(ODocument documentFirst, String classNameFirst,
        String fieldNameFirst, ODocument documentSecond, String classNameSecond, String fieldNameSecond) {

    releaseOne2ManyRelationship(documentFirst, classNameFirst, fieldNameFirst, Arrays.asList(documentSecond),
        classNameSecond, fieldNameSecond);
    }

    public static void releaseOne2OneRelationship(ODocument documentFirst, String classNameFirst, String fieldNameFirst,
        Collection<? extends ODocument> documentsSecond, String classNameSecond, String fieldNameSecond) {

    // left side
    setReference(documentFirst, classNameFirst, fieldNameFirst, null);
    // right side
    for (ODocument documentSecond : documentsSecond) {
        setReference(documentSecond, classNameSecond, fieldNameSecond, null);
    }
    }

    public static void releaseOne2OneRelationship(ODocument documentFirst, String classNameFirst, String fieldNameFirst,
        ODocument documentSecond, String classNameSecond, String fieldNameSecond) {

    releaseOne2OneRelationship(documentFirst, classNameFirst, fieldNameFirst, Arrays.asList(documentSecond),
        classNameSecond, fieldNameSecond);
    }

    /**
     * @return {@code true} if reference collection is now empty; {@code false}
     *         otherwise
     */
    private static boolean removeFromReferenceCollection(ODocument orid, String className, String fieldName,
        ORID value) {

    Collection<ORID> refCollection = new HashSet<>(getReferenceCollection(orid, className, fieldName));
    refCollection.remove(value);
    setReferenceCollection(orid, className, fieldName, refCollection);
    return refCollection.isEmpty();
    }

    public static void setReference(ODocument document, String className, String fieldName, OIdentifiable reference) {

    if (isValid(document, className)) {
        document.field(fieldName, reference, OType.LINK).save();
    } else
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("For " + document);
    }

    private static void setReferenceCollection(ODocument document, String className, String fieldName,
        Collection<? extends ORID> value) {

    if (isValid(document, className)) {
        document.field(fieldName, value, OType.LINKSET).save();
    } else
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("For " + document);
    }
}
```